# Changing language keyboard OSGeo Live

Tags: internationalization, osgeo-live

How can I change the language of the keyboard in OSGeo live? 
As described here https://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/internationalisation_quickstart.html does not do the trick for me. 
I do not have `Preferences ‣ Keyboard Input Methods`. I only have `Preferences ‣ Keyboard and Mouse`. In there I cannot find anything useful... `Preferences ‣ Languages` does not help neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried running the following command in a terminal

```
setxkbmap de
```

Change `de` to the language that you want. If you want to make the changes persistent, then add the above command to your bashrc file:

```
echo "setxkbmap de" >> ~/.bashrc
```

You can read more about setxkbmap [here](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.xhtml)

Comment: awesome, thanks. btw you meant `setxkbmap` I suppose